# aliasing a scanned text (removing blurry or non black pixels)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, photo-editing, anti-aliasing, scanning

I have a scanned text like this:
[image]

And I want something like this:
[image]
Do you have any idea how can I achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menu Image → Adjustment → Threshold

[image]